# My PHP file wont insert HTML data into a MySql database table

Tags: mysql, php, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, I am working on creating a website. An HTML page I have has a form that gets the user data:

```
<form action="Data.php" style="position: fixed; top: 60px; left: 5px;" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Create Account</legend>
    Username: <br>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <br>
    Password:<br>
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name ="Submit" value="Create">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

it then sends it to a php file called Data.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $host = "localhost:3306";
    $username = "Arthos";
    $password = "Pancake101!";
    $database = "userinfo";

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $connect = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
    $query = "INSERT INTO 'users'('username', 'email', 'password') VALUES ("'.$user.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$pass.'")";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

    mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

I do not have a clue how to view php echos or mysql errors in vs code. I am using a base html project, and they are not appearing in the debug console.  I can send what the database looks like if it is needed.

EDIT:
New php code with PDO, still not working:

```
<?php
echo "Made it!";
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=userinfo;charset=utf8mb4";
  $options = [
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false, // turn off emulation mode for "real" prepared statements
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //turn on errors in the form of exceptions
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, //make the default fetch be an associative array
  ];
  try {
      $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "username", "password", $options);
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
      $stmt->execute([$_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']]);
      $stmt = null;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      error_log($e->getMessage());
      exit('Something weird happened'); //something a user can understand
  }
    ?>
```

EDIT 2:
I got the php file to run. I had to mess with some weird Visual Studio code, and it apparently couldn't find my `php.exe` file, so that's now working.
But now I am getting the error:

> "Driver not found" for my php file, so I'll have to look into that now.
>   I have not made any changes to the code that can be seen in the `Data.php` copy up above.

For the last problem, I needed to uncomment a line in `php.ini`. If you have this problem go into your `php.ini` file, edit it, to get rid of the semicolon before:
 `; extension=pdo_mysql`
It should really be: `extension=pdo_mysql`

Comment: Debug console is for debugger output. Have you configured Xdebug? Do you start a debug session with breakpoints and stuff? If you just want to inspect what `echo` prints you can merely look at the browser.

Comment: Regarding your edit... Are you asking how to see `Something weird happened` inside Visual Studio Code when the query crashes? Or the question does not have anything to do with the editor?

Comment: its a bit of both, im not seeing anything regarding php in the editor, and the original question was why the code wasn't inserting the data into the mysql table

Answer (score 0):

Well ..

1. table and column names dont belong in single-quotes as this is used by mysql to mark string-data and similar (like datetime). You should use `backticks` to encase table and column names.

> table `tableName`....

2. please read up on sql-injection - your method of building the query-string by hand invites for sql-injection (in your case nothing keeps a malicious user typing in SQL-commands in the password-field ... he simply types " '); drop table users; -- " (without the double-quotes) and your database breaks .. as an example) https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp
3. clear text passwords ... please use a well established hashing method like sha-256

you might want to use prepared (sql-)statements that mysqli offers .. but I suggest you take the time to learn PDO

Aside from that for your debugging question - Visual studio offers not only debug .. but also an output view ... where  you should be able to see your echo / var_dump ... 
You should also use try-catch exception handling in PHP incase your database operation fails - starting with creating the database connection (which could fail if the db-server is down) to the query failing due to syntax-error like in your case ... if that is really your used code, it breaks because of the mentioned hint 1) - if you want to indicate table and column names .. use ` (back-ticks)